# Is a fatbike easy to keep upright in uneven melting slush?

Tags: winter, fatbike

There's one condition that bicycles with typical tire widths don't handle well: uneven melting slush. This generally happens in spring, when snow is melting. On a road that hasn't been plowed often enough, the layer of hard packed snow and ice on the road can be thick. When it stays hard and doesn't melt, this isn't a problem for bicycles as long as they have studded tires. However, when that hard packed snow and ice starts to melt, it generally doesn't melt directly to water, but rather softens into an uneven melting slush. When bicycles with typical tire widths are ridden on this kind of slush, the bicycle tires don't float on this slush but rather sink and create a groove in it. The problem is, this slush is generally uneven and quite dense, much denser than freshly fallen snow, so the tires don't want to go straight but rather often veer to left and right unpredictably. This can cause it hard to maintain a balance.

Today I observed this again. I was hoping the roads would be in good condition, consisting mostly of melting ice and pavement from which the ice had already melted, but encountered this dangerous kind of slush many times during a ride of less than 3 km to a grocery store. With 35mm studded tires and 4 bar tire pressure, maintaining balance was often hard.

Does a fatbike handle this kind of melting uneven slush better? Would it float on it, thanks to its lower tire pressure? Or would it still sink but be much easier to maintain balance since the contact surface is much wider?

Comment: Have you tried to lower the pressure? 2.5 bar would be a good start. If it works, wider tire will help as well, but the pressure is essential and is much easier to change than the tire size.

Comment: @fraxinus from my experience on slushy snow, it doesn't really make a difference whether you run 2.5 bar or 4 bar (or even more). Either is far harder than the snow can withstand. You have to go to _really_ low pressures; in Bergen I sometimes went as low as 0.6 bar on my MTB and only then does it avoid the unpredictable side-veering. But such low pressure makes the bike roll very poorly on tarmac, and it's basically impossble with street tyres. Now in Stockholm I just keep full road pressure and accept that slush will try to kill me (fortunately cycleways are cleared quite well here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say yes. I was out bike orienteering today in Helsinki with a studded-tire fatbike, riding hard, with pretty much no problems. It's now well above freezing, and it's slush, hard-packed snow, and wet ice everywhere, which is pretty much as bad as it gets.

A fatbike will not float on slush when it's this far in the melting stage, but it also won't be bothered by it all that much. It is definitely going to wiggle around under you a bit, but fatbikes in general feel much more stable than narrow-tired bikes when they do that, probably because a small wiggle is not enough to take the center of balance outside the tire's footprint.

Don't assume a fatbike would relieve of the necessity of knowing how to ride on poor surfaces though. You'll eventually lose traction if you ask too much of it, so on marginal days like today you have to look ahead and decide what you can and cannot ask of the bike. And if you ride too fast into really big bumps, the bike will throw you off, just like any rigid bike will.

In the 17 years I've had a fatbike, I have most winters had studded tires on some other bikes as well for the days when it's not that bad, because they are slightly faster on good days. But with age comes not being in such a hurry, and I've pretty much stopped riding the other bikes in winter, because on a fatbike I can be most confident that I can always get there, eventually.